# How to output highest score and name associated with it - liquid logic

Tags: shopify, liquid

I need to output the highest_score and the name associated with it. The code outputs the highest_score but it's not associated with the right name. I guess it needs a for within a for loop, but I'm not quite sure how to construct it.

Here's my code:

```
{%- capture list_of_scores -%}
{{wa}}|Wine Advocate,{{bh}}|Burghound,{{ag}}|Vinous,{{jr}}|Jancis Robinson,{{jg}}|John Gilman
{%- endcapture -%}
{%- capture list_of_scores_num -%}{{wa}},{{bh}},{{ag}},{{jr}},{{jg}}{%- endcapture -%}

{% assign scores_array = list_of_scores | split: ',' %}
{% assign scores = list_of_scores_num | split: ',' %}
{% assign highest_score = scores | first | plus: 0 %}


{% for score_val in scores %}
{% assign cur_score = score_val | plus: 0 %}
{% if cur_score >= highest_score %}
{% assign highest_score = score_val | plus: 0 %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% for score_and_name in scores_array %}
{% assign split_score_and_name = score_and_name | split: '|' %}
{% assign score = split_score_and_name[0] %}
{% assign score = highest_score %}
{% assign name = split_score_and_name[1] %}
{% endfor %}

<span>{{ highest_score }}</span>
<h5>{{ name }}</h5>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
{% assign wa = 12 %}
{% assign bh = 16 %}
{% assign ag = 26 %}
{% assign jr = 6 %}
{% assign jg = 11 %}

{%- capture list_of_scores -%}
    {{wa}}|Wine Advocate,
    {{bh}}|Burghound,
    {{ag}}|Vinous,
    {{jr}}|Jancis Robinson,
    {{jg}}|John Gilman
{%- endcapture -%}
{%- capture list_of_scores_num -%}
    {{wa}},
    {{bh}},
    {{ag}},
    {{jr}},
    {{jg}}
{%- endcapture -%}

{% assign scores_array = list_of_scores | split: ',' %}
{% assign scores = list_of_scores_num | split: ',' %}
{% assign highest_score = scores | first | plus: 0 %}

{% assign name = '' %}
{% for score_val in scores %}
    {% assign cur_score = score_val | plus: 0 %}
    {% if cur_score >= highest_score %}
        {% assign highest_score = score_val | plus: 0 %}
        {% assign name = scores_array[forloop.index0] | split: '|' | last %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

<span>{{ highest_score }}</span>
<h5>{{ name }}</h5>
```

The main difference is that we moved the `name` value outside of the loop as an empty variable and inside the loop that we check the highest number we assign the name variable using the `forloop.index0` using the following code:

`{% assign name = scores_array[forloop.index0] | split: '|' | last %}`

So we need only 1 loop.

Comment: you've saved my life today. Thank you for your in-depth, clear explanation too.